# Change Table Row Color back to white if it has already been clicked

Tags: javascript

How can the code below be modified to add functionality on top of the existing code such that if the same table row that has already been clicked on (black), and is subsequently clicked on again, that it be changed from black to white?

Jay

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
tr.normal td {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}
tr.highlighted td {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="results" class="scrollingdatagrid">
  <table id="mstrTable" cellspacing="0" border="1">
     <thead>
      <tr> 
        <th>File Number</th>
        <th>Date1</th>
        <th>Date2</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Num.</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr> 
        <td>KABC</td>
        <td>09/12/2002</td>
        <td>09/12/2002</td>
        <td>Submitted</td>
        <td>0</td>

      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>KCBS</td>
        <td>09/11/2002</td>
        <td>09/11/2002</td>
        <td>Lockdown</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>

      <tr> 
        <td>WFLA</td>
        <td>09/11/2002</td>
        <td>09/11/2002</td>
        <td>Submitted</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>WTSP</td>
        <td>09/15/2002</td>
        <td>09/15/2002</td>
        <td>In-Progress</td>
        <td>10</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
(
  function( )
  {
      var trows = document.getElementById("mstrTable").rows;

      for ( var t = 1; t < trows.length; ++t )
      {
          trow = trows[t];
          trow.className = "normal";
          trow.onclick = highlightRow;
      }

      function highlightRow( )
      {
          for ( var t = 1; t < trows.length; ++t )
          {
              trow = trows[t];
              trow.className = ( trow == this ) ? "highlighted" : "normal";
          }
      }
  }
)();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: JsFiddle w/ this example code: http://jsfiddle.net/RFQ76/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change this:

```
trow.className = ( trow == this ) ? "highlighted" : "normal";
```

To this:

```
trow.className = ( trow == this && trow.className != "highlighted") ? "highlighted" : "normal";
```

Here is a jsFiddle with the full code: http://jsfiddle.net/uFrvN/

Comment: Flawless and lightweight. Thank you so much :)

Comment: No problem. If this solved your problem, go ahead and mark it as the solution!

Answer (score 0):

This will remove all classes and sets only the needed class.

```
function highlightRow( )
{
    for ( var t = 1; t < trows.length; ++t )
    {
        trow = trows[t];
        if(trow == this) {
            c = trow.className;
            trow.className = "";
            trow.className = ( c == "normal") ? "highlighted" : "normal";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Love the logic used here. My eyes must be tired. I didn't see that I could even do this. This example works great too. More than one way to skin a cat =\